# Ensure hardware acceleration feature working

Tags: firefox, gpu, hardware-acceleration, top, ps

Firefox in my ubuntu distribution typically takes up high resources of CPU. Since hardware acceleration is an often suggested way to ensure performance, i have enabled it under the browser preference, so to say. However, i am not getting sense of my CPU being relieved from the spikes of resource consumption. So, how may i actually monitor that the GPU enabled hardware acceleration is working well via a `top` or a `ps` command. And how do i optimize the use of GPU in browsing?

Comment: Try using the address "about:support", and go to the Graphics section and check that GPU acceleration is enabled. It may not be supported on your GPU.